# Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

After run application and click button, which is connected to next controller I get this error:

> 2016-04-26 12:49:32.743 Kalkulator[7401:159800] Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-oFL-gV-w1Q
>   2016-04-26 12:49:32.744 Kalkulator[7401:159800] Missing proxy for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-ufI-Y0-ejo
>   2016-04-26 12:49:32.753 Kalkulator[7401:159800] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key searchAnything.'

I don't have (and I didn't have) any "searchAnything". searchAnything is in another group/project. There I don't have any error.

Solutions from:
[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' : iOS app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538720/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception-ios-app-cras)
and
[What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu)

didn't help me.

I don't know how to add all project here so I sent my mini-project-from-tutorial to [sendspace](https://www.sendspace.com/file/wiok6p)

Comment: `tableController.m` has an `IBOutlet` named `searchAnything`.

Comment: Yes. I know. But I am not using tableController.m and I don't have any error with tableController.m part

Comment: I didn't opened your project in XCode, just searched in the files. `tableView.storyboard` references also to an `IBOulet` named `searchAnything`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and check whether the outlet connection is with Exclamation symbol if so remove it and then give proper connection to get it done.You have to select the appropriate viewcontroller which is getting crash.

Comment: No, there isn't any exclamation symbol.

Comment: Are you using any search controller?Uisearch or anything?Defined any predicate values?

Comment: In other group with other storyboard (which storyboard hasn't this problem). With this storyboard I didn't use any search controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some outlet in the ViewController that you loading on click of button is not perfectly set. Please check for the following -

1. Main view outlet may not set
2. Any of the UIObject, may have double outlet(may be you change the object name and format to remove last outlet from the connection Inspector)

Comment: I didn't find any problem with this.

Comment: go to break point navigator and add a exception break point, this may be helpful to determine on which line you are getting the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Push segue is deprecated from iOS 8.0 and later.

**Temporary solution:**
Change your Deployment Target to 9.0 and it will work.

**Permanent Solution:**
Create a new Xcode project copy all files except storyboards from existing project to new project and design the storyboard as per the existing one from the beginning.set your deployment target to iOS 8.0